# Rails: How to display results with Yaml in console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, yaml

I'm retrieving some records from a database using `user = Users.all` in the console but they are very unreadable.

I know that Yaml will make it more legible but don't know how to convert the results to Yaml.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
require 'yaml'
puts user.to_yaml
```

Comment: thanks, I think I had done it before without having to use 'puts'. Will accept as answer once system allows me.

Answer (score 2):

You can also just prepend a 'y' to your command in the console:

```
y User.all
```

To get yaml output.

Comment: This doesn't work for me in `zeus console` -- I get: "NoMethodError: undefined method `y' for main:Object"

Answer (score 0):

You can type "y _" after the output like:

```
User.all
y _
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want your output to be ready for Rails fixtures then restrict it to the attributes:

```
User.all.each {|u| y u.attributes}
```